# Search an index in all stored procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to get a list of all the stored procedures that use an index from a table. My task is to delete the indexes that are not being used in the database or that are not overloaded with indexes.

Well first I get all indexes from a table:

```
DECLARE @tableName AS VARCHAR(50) = 'tbl_INVOICES';
SELECT
    IND.name as IndexName
    FROM sys.indexes IND
        INNER JOIN sys.index_columns IND_COL on IND.index_id = IND_COL.index_id and IND.object_id = IND_COL.object_id
    WHERE IND.object_id = OBJECT_ID(@tableName)
        AND is_included_column = 0
    ORDER BY 
        IndexName
```

with each one of these indexes that I obtain, I have to do another search, the expected result is a list of the procedures stored with the name of the index that they are using

```
SELECT
    OBJ.name AS [object_name],
    IND.name AS index_name,
    IND.type_desc,
    IND_USA_STATS.user_seeks, 
    IND_USA_STATS.user_scans,
    IND_USA_STATS.user_lookups, 
    IND_USA_STATS.user_updates,
    OBJ.type,
    IND.type,
    IND_USA_STATS.index_id
FROM
    sys.indexes IND
    INNER JOIN
    sys.objects OBJ ON IND.[object_id] = OBJ.[object_id]
    LEFT JOIN
    sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats IND_USA_STATS ON IND.[object_id] = IND_USA_STATS.[object_id] AND
        IND.index_id = IND_USA_STATS.index_id AND
        IND_USA_STATS.database_id = DB_ID(@tableName)
    WHERE
    OBJ.type IN ('P') 
ORDER BY 
    index_name
```

Well, it took a long time and I can't get the list, this was the last attempt I made and it doesn't give me results, the question here is **how do I get the list of stored procedures that uses a determined index?**

Comment: you should be searching the plan cache for queries that use an index. Just because an index exists on a table doesn't mean it will be used. https://littlekendra.com/2017/01/24/how-to-find-queries-using-an-index-and-queries-using-index-hints/

Comment: You don't know at any given point in time what indexes a SP uses... its all down to the query plan... which can change. Unless you use a table hint to force an index. I would suggest checking out the tools provided by Brent Ozar.

Comment: @MitchWheat I see the link you sent is very useful, thanks.

Comment: There are system DMV's to find out about index usage - which you can use to figure out what indexes aren't being used - e.g. here: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/256/discovering-unused-indexes/ - but **be aware** : in many systems, certain indexes will only be used every end of month, end of quarter, and quite possibly even end of year - but they are **crucial** for end-of-period reporting in those times! Don't drop them too easily!